# setting up apache and php on mac os x 10.8.5

Tags: php, macos, apache

I followed the link http://machiine.com/2013/how-to-install-apache-and-php-on-a-mac-with-osx-10-8-mamp-part-1/  localhost shows like It Works.but when i use localhost/~anu, it shows "safari cannot connect the server localhost".Can anyone help me?

Comment: are you actually putting 'localhost/~username' ?

Comment: ~username should be a placeholder for your username

Comment: i tried localhost/~anu.

Comment: is there an index.php/index.html in your username directory?

Comment: no.i tried like this: localhost/~anu/Sites/phpinfo.php.but i got same error as above i mentioned

Comment: and is there a phpinfo.php file in you /Sites/phpinfo.php?

Comment: yes.i created it using above link(from terminal)